# Django rest self-referencing ForeignKey error Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use parent.set() instead

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Model:

```
class Comment(models.Model, CharField, ListField):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comment_user',
                             blank=True, null=True)
    news = models.ForeignKey(News, related_name='comment_of', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(4)], max_length=200")
    parent_comment = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='parent',
                                       on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:

        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

When I login in admin click comment,there is an error:

**Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use parent.set() instead.**

When I remove:

```
parent_comment = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='parent',
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The error gone.

So,how to modify **parent_comment**,I think the issue is here.